# Difference between Unit tests project in c# and a class library with xunit

Tags: c#, testing

Ok so I have been a long time xunit user, and I have always used it in a class library. Infact I didn't even realize there was an actual unit tests project type.

So my question is...what do you get in a unit tests project you do not get in regular project types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit of the Unit Test project is that the IDE (Visual Studio) recognizes the project, and searches it for tests (like what @Emmanuel Istace indicates).  The reason you might want to choose different unit test frameworks depends on what you're trying to test.  For example, working on testing a multi-threading application using the C# ThreadPool in MSTest consistently hangs for me, so I use NUnit for those types of tests.

Bottom line is this: you should choose your test framework based on what you're trying to test, and choose the best fit.  Visual Studio does a decent job of supporting other test frameworks in VS2015 and VS2013/2012 (not sure about earlier versions), and really, whichever framework you choose, you'll likely end up using a Unit Test Project for it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A unit test project is a class library project, take a look at the csproj you'll see there's nothing fundamentally different.

Unit test project include reference to MSTest and test runner.

Comment: You also get some extra Visual Studio functionality. E.g. if you right click on a unit test project the context menu is different than if you right click on a class library project.